# React Native - How to connect to AWS DynamoDB table

Tags: reactjs, react-native, amazon-dynamodb

I am following this aws tutorial to create my first React Native app which connects to AWS:

[aws tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/react-native-getting-started.html#react-native-getting-started-configure-aws-amplify)

Everything installs fine and my app runs happily with the following imports:

```
**import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import aws_exports from './aws-exports'; 
Amplify.configure(aws_exports);**
```

I would now like to connect the app to an existing DynamoDB table called 'Movement' but the tutorial only shows how to create a new table with the NoSQL wizard using: **awsmobile database enable --prompt**

Could you point me to a (simple) resource that shows me how to connect to an existing DynamoDB table and perform CRUD operations?

These are the steps I have followed:

I have a DynamoDB table called: movement
It has 3 items : hub_id, on_time, message

Hub_id is the primary partition key
on_time is the primary sort key

The table holds sensor data (movement, temperature that sort of thing) in the message item.

I created the app using :

**create-react-native-app dbapp**

I have then run: 
    **awsmobile configure**
    **aws mobile init**

Installed amplify:
    **npm install aws-amplify --save**

I created the project in mobile hub.

I then linked the app to the hub using:
    **awsmobile init 15c482e2-2c3c-11e8-8692-fblahblahblah3**

CLI responded : **Successfully linked AWS Mobile Hub project: dbapp-datetime!**

So all looks good so far (I hope!)

I then altered app.js to look like this: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/kJKXM55M)

**npm start** runs just fine with no errors that I can see.

The problem that I currently have is that I don't have a clue about how to query my table and populate variables so that I can use them in the view.

Comment: Have you looked at the AWS documentation? https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/api_guide should help. You may need another library like Axios or Thunk if you are new to calling restFul API's in React/React-Native

Comment: Thanks I have used that resource and it enabled me to create the CloudLogic API. Where I am falling down is how to connect up the API to the DynamoDB table. I realise this may be a conceptual problem on my part!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Posting your code is the easiest way to get a "good" answer quickly

Comment: Fair comment - I'll reformat the question with more precise information.

Comment: Great rewrite of the question, I found a package on github called was-mobile-react-native-starter (https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-react-native-starter) that has pretty good code detail that looks like it could answer your question.  Another more specific example can be found in this file https://github.com/mhart/react-server-routing-example/blob/master/db.js in github repository mhart/react-server-routing-example https://github.com/mhart/react-server-routing-example. Hope that helps

Comment: These are great resources Steve. I'll  use them and close down the question. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Hi @Dunsany Are you able to connect to DynamoDb table ?

Comment: Yes I have connected to DynamoDB. I forgot to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

Following the resources suggested (thanks SteveB). I connected to the DynamoDB table, queried it and used the data in my app.

In case you are also stuck, here is an edited version of my code. Apologies to everyone that gets to edit this - I know it is awful. Does work though :)

```
      // Use db to query the dynamoDB table - setup query parameters first //


var params = {
    TableName : "myproject-mobilehub-123456789-Sensors",
    ProjectionExpression:"hub_id, details.on_time, details.sensor_name, 
details.temperature, details.battery",
    KeyConditionExpression: "hub_id = :hid AND begins_with(on_time, :d)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":hid":"testdevice01",
        ":d": today,
        },
    Limit: 1,
    ScanIndexForward: false
};

//Execute db query using params

    async getQuery() {
    db.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) { console.log("Query failed.");
    } else {
        console.log("Query succeeded.");
    };

    data.Items.forEach(function(details) {

        //display variables

console.log(details.hub_id,details.details.sensor_name,details.details.on_time, 
details.details.temperature, details.details.battery,); 

        //Populate variables
        hubid = details.hub_id;
        currroom = details.details.sensor_name;
        roomtime = details.details.on_time;
        roomtemp = details.details.temperature;
        roombattery = details.details.battery + "%";
    });

}});

//Finally populate text with variables

this.setState({
  displayText1: currroom,
  displayText2: roombattery,
  displayText3: roomtime,
  displayText4: roomtemp

});
```